# readVertices in java implementation not reading vertices from json

Tags: java, json, graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I have exported some vertices belong to same category in using `writeVertices()` method of `GraphSONWriter` to one `json` file.

now i imported that file using gremlin as:

`gremlin>  graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).reader().create().readVertices(fileinputStream, Attachable.Method.create(graph), Attachable.Method.create(graph), Direction.BOTH);`

this successfully imported all the vertices.
BUT

I tried same query in `JAVA` it didn't gave any error but the vertices didn't imported.?

```
public JsonNode importObjects()throws JsonProcessingException{
    Map<String,Object> out = new HashMap<>();
    try{
        FileInputStream fileinputStream=new FileInputStream(new File("vertics.json"));
        TitanGraph graph = getDataSource().getGraph();
        Iterator<Vertex>vitr=graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).reader().create().readVertices(fileinputStream, Attachable.Method.create(graph), Attachable.Method.create(graph) ,Direction.BOTH);
        graph.tx().commit();
        out.put("Success", "imported objects!");    
        return JsonHelper.convert(out);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        out.put("Error", e);
        return JsonHelper.convert(out);
} }
```

Comment: i can't think of a reason why this code wouldn't work equally well in the console or a java application.

Comment: So any alternatives?
i tried using `readGraph()` method.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more helpful to share the code that is not working?

Comment: Added java code.